# Mostrar dato de base de datos que esta en otro id despues del id 0

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero mostrar datos de una base de datos. Esto ya lo sé, pero solo se mostrar lo todo lo que está en el id 0 de la tabla de la base, y ahora quiero mostrar lo que esta en la tabla 2. Por ejemplo

```
 id   dato1   dato2
 0    abc     def
 1    ghi     jkl
```

Bien, lo que está en "ID:0" ya lo se mostrar, pero lo que está en "ID: 1" no se como se muestra, esta es mi metodo para mostrar:

```
$sql_dbdatos = "SELECT * from datos";
$result_dbdatos= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_dbdatos);
$rows_dbdatos = mysqli_fetch_array($result_dbdatos);
```

Y esto lo pongo en una tabla:

```
<li>  ' . $rows_dbpartidos['dato1'] . '</li>
```

Comment: Pregunta muy similar a la que ya hiciste como MatiPHP. Por favor, no crees múltiples cuentas.

Comment: Dios, tanto cuesta responder la respuesta? En el otro me hicieron un choclo que me hicieron calentar, y nada que ver con la pregunta la respuesta y **ENCIMA** me criticaba

Comment: No es la primera vez que actúas de este modo lamentable. Invertí un montón de tiempo en la otra respuesta para tratar de explicarte los fundamentos de las cosas pero se ve que te gustan las *soluciones fáciles*.  Si sigues por ese camino y piensas dedicarte a la programación, no pasarás de ser un programador mediocre. Perdona que diga palabras tan duras, pero es que da pena cuando uno lee comentarios como los tuyos. Si quieres ser programador te recomiendo que vuelvas a los fundamentos, porque se nota que te faltan y que aprendas a aceptar las críticas. Ayudan a crecer y a aprender.

Comment: Ves, hace falta eso? En la otra pregunta criticabas como lo tenía armado, te agradecí, pero no respondía en nada a la pregunta.

Comment: El problema es que la pregunta era (y es) de muy baja calidad: el problema está regular explicado, apenas se entiende qué es lo que quieres, parece que mezclas los conceptos de tabla y fila, los ejemplos y datos que presentas no se entienden bien... si quieres respuestas de calidad debes escribir preguntas de calidad. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Por favor, esto no tiene nada que ver con la pregunta, no me importa que sea una critica constructiva.

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que agregar un ciclo `while` asi:

```
$sql_dbpartidos = "SELECT * from datos";
$result_dbdatos= mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_dbdatos);
echo '<ul>';
while($rows_dbdatos = mysqli_fetch_array($result_dbdatos)) {

    echo '<li>  ' . $rows_dbdatos['dato1'] . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Como lo muestro despues con un echo? Supongamos que quiero mostrar el dato " GHI"

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta.  En mi ejemplo deberia de mostrar los dos registros, el "ABC" y el "GHI".

Comment: Pero yo los quiero mostrar en dos "<li>" distintos

Comment: Por eso, este codigo genera un "<li>" por cada registro en tu tabla.

Comment: Ya probaste mi codigo?

Comment: Si, no me carga la página.

Comment: Ahí está, me carga pero no me muestra nada